# How to spilt total hours into 4 group

Tags: php

I am working on a project to get the total hours in seconds and I need to spilt total hours into different groups to pay for the staff as per the total working hours in each month
for example :

```
     $montylyhours = '108000';
     $rate1 = "0.41666"; //25$ per hour
     $rate2 = "0.83333"; //50$  per hour
     $rate3 = "1.25"; //75$ per hour
     $rate4 = "1.4166"; //85$ per hour
     $basic = "2550"; //Basic Salary
    
     $hour = "3800"; //1hour
     $hour30 = "108000"; //30hour
     $hour60 = "216000"; //60hour
     $hour90 = "324000"; //90hour
```

above mention the rate for each second
for example, if someone works 30 hours means 108000 seconds he will get

```
$total_salary = $rate1 * hour30;
```

but if Someone work less or more than 90 hours I want to pay to him diffrent rate
example : $rate1 from 1 hour till 30 hours // 3600 to 108000 seconds
$rate2 from 30 to 60 hours // 108000 - 216000 seconds
$rate3 from 60 to 90 hours // 216000 - 324000 seconds
$rate4 from more than 90 hours // more than 324000 seconds

what I did but I failed I got the wrong salary

```
if($montylyhours < $hour){
$salary1 = $basic + ($rate1 * $montylyhours)/60;

}elseif((max(min($montylyhours, $hour30), $hour) == $montylyhours)){
$salary2 = $basic + ($rate1 * $montylyhours)/60;

}elseif((max(min($montylyhours, $hour60), $hour30) == $montylyhours)){
$salary3 = $basic + ($rate2 * $hour30)/60;

}elseif((max(min($montylyhours, $hour90), $hour60) == $montylyhours)){
$salary4 = $basic + ($rate3 * $hour30)/60;

}elseif($montylyhours > $hour90){
$salary5 = $basic + ($rate4 * $montylyhours-$hour90)/60;
}

$total_salary = $salary1+$salary2+$salary3+$salary4+$salary5;
echo round($total_salary ,0).' USD';
```

I hope you understand, the system will get the total monthly working hours then I need to pay him with different rates 0-30 / 30-60 / 60-90 / more than 90
then Sum total salary.

Thanks

Comment: 1 Read your code again carefully, there are obvious inconsistent mistakes. 2 Why do you use these crabbed `(max(min` calls? Why not use `> && <` instead? 3 If-elseif-else statement is exclusive, only one of the `$salaryN` variable will be set. If you want to compute progressive salaries you shouldn't use `else` here.